# Are all tables available in SEDE available in Google BigQuery's Stack Overflow dataset?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Specifically, I'm looking for tables like CloseReasonTypes and PostHistoryTypeId. Is there a schema somewhere? I only see a few tables in the Google BigQuery UI:

[image: Stack Overflow data set tables on Google BigQuery]

Do I need to use the Data Explorer if I want to use these tables?

Answer (score 3):

## Are all tables available in SEDE available in Google BigQuery's Stack Overflow dataset?

SEDE has additional tables, which allow for simpler and / or faster queries on the dataset, and others which allow for listing the meaning of values.

## Given examples

- CloseReasonTypes

  This converts from a CloseTypeId to a name and description.
- PostHistoryTypes

  This does the same, but for the diffent types of post history events.

## Why are these ommitted from the Google BigQuery dataset

I would guess they were omitted so that the data can be sourced directly from the data dump, instead of needing to be processed first.